# Can Mac Phone Connector Sync to Picasa?

Tags: sync, phone-connector-mac

Windows Phone Connector for Mac allows you to sync your photos with your iPhoto library. I don't use iPhoto and there is no option to sync with Picasa.

Is there any workaround/hack that will allow synching to Picasa without duplicating the photos into iPhoto?

Comment: Have you looked at the Picasa Web Albums for mobile phones? Visit m.google.com from your phone to get tot he site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of picasa apps out in the [Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=picasa).

[Picasa+](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=5d6373ce-ac98-4a85-b213-8d8790850f28) is one app that allow you to upload your photos to Picasa.